# EmberJs - {{#each}} and array of Class instances

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I've defined a class like below

```
const OpenedCaseStatus = Ember.Object.extend({
  caseid: -1,
  isActive: false,
  selectedTabIndex : -1      
});

export default OpenedCaseInfo;
```

In my `caseInfo` service I have created an array `openedCases` which contains instances of class `OpenedCaseStatus`.

In one of my component I am injecting the `caseInfo` service and then in my template I am trying to print case information like:

```
<div>
    <ul>
        {{#each casesInfoService.openedCases as |caseStatus|}}
            <li>caseStatus.caseid</li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>    
</div>
```

But this is not printing the data. Earlier it was working when I was populating the `openedCases` array with anonymous objects like below:

```
this.get('openedCases').pushObject({caseid: 1, isActive: true, selectedTabIndex: 0});
this.get('openedCases').pushObject({caseid: 2, isActive: false, selectedTabIndex: 1});
this.get('openedCases').pushObject({caseid: 3, isActive: true, selectedTabIndex: 3});
```

My question is why `{{#each}}` is not working with class instances. Is there any alternative?

Comment: Well, are you sure there **are** open cases? Try adding an `{{else}}NO OPEN CASES` inside your `#each` loop. And/or, show us the code for the service, and for how you are injecting it. Also, check your spelling; you call the service `caseInfo` in one place and `casesInfoService` in another.

Comment: `casesInfoService` points to the `caseInfo` service. In my component I've injected the service like  `casesInfoService: Ember.inject.service('cases-info')`. However, it was definitely a spelling mistake. The sample code above is correct but in my actual application there was a spelling mistake in the `openedCases` variable. So a very good pointer.

Comment: So is the problem solved, or not?

Comment: Yes its solved now. Thanks!